# R: how to simultaneously reverse and apply transformation to axes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scaletransform

In a plot, constructed with the use of `ggplot2` package, for example, such one:

```
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist))+geom_col()
```

the axes can be transformed by applying appropriate directives. For example, `+scale_y_continuous(trans="reverse")` draws the coordinate axis from top towards bottom, and `scale_y_continuous(trans="sqrt")` makes a nonlinear transformation. I need to combine both functions, that is have axes origin on top and log or sqrt transformation on y axis. Applying the transformations one by one (i.e. `+scale_y_reverse() ... + scale_y_log()`) gives a warning: `Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will replace the existing scale.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
require(scales);
rev_sqrt_trans <- function() {
    scales::trans_new(
        name = "rev_sqrt", 
        transform = function(x) -sqrt(abs(x)), 
        inverse = function(x) x^2);
}

require(ggplot2);
ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) + geom_col() + scale_y_continuous(trans = "rev_sqrt")
```

You can optimise the breaks when defining the new transformation, see `?trans_new`.

[image]

Comment: Direct application of this recipe yielded an error:
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'rev_sqrt_trans' of mode 'function' was not found

Comment: Ah yes, apologies! I forgot to wrap the new transformation inside a function. It should work now.